# Azure Java SDK - how to retrieve RBAC roles of an User

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-rbac, azure-sdk-for-java

We have a requirement to check the Authorization permissions of an User before executing business logic. I am not able to find an example or tutorial to retrieve the Roles of an User, using Azure Java SDK.

Answer (score 0):

We have Rest API by which we can retrieve all roles assigned to a subscription. Using HTTP request we can retrieve all the role assignments and then we can search for user

Code:

```
String api = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?api-version=2015-07-01" ;  
// Here substitute the SubstriptionID  
System._out_.println( "Hello World!" );  
HttpClient client = HttpClient._newHttpClient_();  
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest._newBuilder_()  
.GET()  
.uri(URI._create_(api))  
.build();  
HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request , HttpResponse.BodyHandlers._ofString_());  
System._out_.print(response.body());

// The following the has to parsed to find whether the user is present or not
```

Here are the few related Microsoft Documents for complete information.

[Role Assignments - List - REST API (Azure Authorization) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/role-assignments/list#code-try-0)

[Use the Azure SDK for Java | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/overview)

Comment: Powershell command 'az role assignment list --assignee user@company.com --all' is giving result in powershell but no results for below code snippet.
TokenCredential azureCliCredential = new AzureCliCredentialBuilder().build();
GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(azureCliCredential)).buildClient();
AppRoleAssignmentCollectionPage appRoleAssignments = graphClient.users("objectid of user@company.com").appRoleAssignments().buildRequest().filter().get();
System.out.println(appRoleAssignments.getCount());

Comment: Opened another question to reach more people, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71376890/any-permissions-are-missing-azure-rbac-vs-power-shell