# Any permissions are missing Azure RBAC vs Power shell?

Tags: java, azure, azure-powershell, azure-java-sdk, azure-rbac

Powershell command 'az role assignment list --assignee user@company.com --all' is giving result in powershell but no results for below code snippet.

```
TokenCredential azureCliCredential = new AzureCliCredentialBuilder().build();
GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(azureCliCredential)).buildClient();
AppRoleAssignmentCollectionPage appRoleAssignments = graphClient.users("objectid of user@company.com").appRoleAssignments().buildRequest().get();
System.out.println(appRoleAssignments);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is not working is because the two things you are trying are for different things all together.

`'az role assignment list --assignee user@company.com --all'` is to get Azure RBAC role assignments i.e. roles assigned to a user for managing Azure Subscriptions.

However `AppRoleAssignmentCollectionPage appRoleAssignments = graphClient.users("objectid of user@company.com").appRoleAssignments().buildRequest().get();` gets the roles assigned to the user for an application in Azure AD.

To get Azure RBAC role assignments using code, your will need to use [`Azure SDK for Java`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/overview)

Comment: thanks @Gaurav Mantri, actually my requirement is to get RBAC role assignments using Azure SDK for JAVA, do you have any reference

Comment: @dev4java - I tried to look up the exact function you would need to use and closest I could get to was this: https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-resourcemanager/2.12.0/com/azure/resourcemanager/AccessManagement.html.

Comment: the above suggested 'AzureResourceManager' is giving the all the role definitions available on a resource but not what are the roles assigned (role definition details )to the user